# Logon to ServerFault with android is problematic with Google

Tags: bug

All - mobile on Android.

When I switched over from OpenId to using Google for auth, the logon page repeatedly reloads, and I cannot even logon.  Interestingly, if I switch to an incognito browser window, the symptom does not manifest, logon works fine.   Let me know if there is any other info I can provide.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably some "interesting" conflict with cookie data and mobile device handling...

Comment: Yeah, I think the cookie for this site is jacked up.  Probably would be a good idea if we could have some kind of reset session for fhe site.  Not unlike the "log out of all devices/sessions" feature.

Comment: I've had similar issues while using the full-fat site on Android devices.